# LinkExtractor using scrapy in python

Tags: python, scrapy, spyder

I am trying to read a index page to scrape quotes categories from a quote site to learn scrapy. Im new to this!

Im able to read individual pages (categories) with my code, however I would like to read a index page to read the quote pages.

The `def parse_item` part works with individual pages. However I cant get the `LinkExtractor` part to extrapolate the links.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import Rule

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    allowed_domains = ['website.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.website.com/topics'
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('^\/topics.*', )), callback='parse_item')  
    )


    def parse_item(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('#quotesList .grid-item'):                                       
           yield {
              'text': quote.css('a.oncl_q::text').extract_first(),
              'author': quote.css('a.oncl_a::text').extract_first(),
              'tags': quote.css('.kw-box a.oncl_list_kc::text').extract(),
              'category' : response.css('title::text').re(r'(\w+).*')  
            }

        next_page = response.css('div.bq_s.hideInfScroll > nav > ul > li:nth-last-child(1) a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
          next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
          yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this issue out. Whilst there was probably a way to resolve this issue with the `Rule(LinkExtractor`, I instead used cascade of response.css queries to follow the links on the topics page.

This is the final working version...

```
import scrapy

class QuotesBrainy(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Quotes'

start_urls = ['https://www.website.com/topics/']

def parse(self, response):
    # follow links to topic pages
    for href in response.css('a.topicIndexChicklet::attr(href)'):
        yield response.follow(href, self.parse_item)


def parse_item(self, response):
    # iterate through all quotes
    for quote in response.css('#quotesList .grid-item'):                                       
       yield {
          'text': quote.css('a.oncl_q::text').extract_first(),
          'author': quote.css('a.oncl_a::text').extract_first(),
          'tags': quote.css('.kw-box a.oncl_list_kc::text').extract(),
          'category' : response.css('title::text').re(r'(\w+).*')  
        }

    # go through the pagination links to access infinite scroll           
    next_page = response.css('div.bq_s.hideInfScroll > nav > ul > li:nth-last-child(1) a::attr(href)').extract_first()
    if next_page is not None:
      next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
      yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse_item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your mistake:

```
yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

where is your method parse?

Change like this ---->

```
 yield scrapy.follow(url=next_page, callback=self.parse_item)
```

Comment: Thanks but the pagination and def_item part works fine. Im having problems with the LinkExtractor part passing the category URL's to parse_item.